# Estou tentando fazer um programa que receba um número n e retorne todos os primos até n, mas não sei o que esta dando errado

Tags: python

```
numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))

lista_numeros = list(range(1, numero + 1))

primos = []

divisores = 0 

for n in lista_numeros: 
    for count in range (2, n): 
        if (numero % count == 0): 
            divisores =+ 1 

    if divisores == 0: 
        primos.append(n)


print(primos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está com alguns erros, por exemplo: troque esse `=+` por `+=`. Eu fiz as seguintes alterações:

```py
numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))

lista_numeros = list(range(2, numero + 1))

primos = []

divisores = 0

for n in lista_numeros:
    for count in primos:
        if (n % count == 0):
            divisores += 1

    if divisores == 0:
        primos.append(n)

    divisores = 0

print(primos)
```

Comment: Poxa, muito obrigada! Eu estou bem no começo ainda, fiz apenas algumas aulas. Obrigada mesmo!

Comment: De nada. E não é necessário verificar se ele é divisível por todos os números maiores que 1, somente verificar com os números primos.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código não retorna a resposta certa. Caso ainda não tenha conseguido, sugiro que teste esse código:

```
def primo(numero):
    div = 0
    for n in range(1, numero+1):
        if numero % n == 0:
            div += 1 
    return div

numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))
lista = [x for x in range(1, numero)]
primos = []

for n in lista:
    div = primo(n)
    if div == 2:
        primos.append(n)

print(primos)
```

Na função `primo(numero)` recebemos um número para verificar se ele é primo ou não. Como sabemos, um número primo é aquele que só é divisível por 1 ou por ele mesmo, ou seja, ele só tem 2 divisores. 
Portanto na nossa função iniciamos um contador de divisores `div` em 0 e analisamos quantos divisores o número passado por parâmetro tem, percorrendo de 1 até ele. Se ele for divisível incrementamos nosso contador `div`.

Recebemos um número na variável `numero` e depois criamos uma lista que vai de 1 até o número informado. Aqui usei `list comprehension` para gerar a lista. 
Na variável `primos` criamos uma lista para armazenar os numeros primos e depois é só percorrer a lista de numeros e chamar a função `primo()`. Se o resultado da função for 2 significa que o número só tem 2 divisores, logo ele é primo e é adicionado na lista de numeros primos.